# Get all categories and items in a category - laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

```
public function index()
{
    $schedual = schedual::all();
    foreach ($schedual as $s)
    {
      $specialism = specialism::query()->find($s->specialism_id);
      $s->specialism = $specialism['name'];
    }
}
```

I want to display a table that contains categories and its items.
All items under its category.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

your provided code is not helping much can you add some addition code for model and relations too??

```
$schedual  = schedual::with(['specialism(relationship name)' => function($query) {
    $query->where('tablename.cloumnname','=', 'schedual'stablename.columnname');
}])->get();
```

the field in query can be used in vice versa and you also can use schedual's column name directly since it is the model that is loading the relation.
Do review https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships